# How to transform object to array of objects with special rules in DW?

Tags: mule, mule4

I need to transform an object that looks like this:

```
    {
    myKey: 'abc',
    att1:'val1',
    att2:'val2',
    ,,,
    attN: 'valN' 
    }
```

to

```
[
 {myKey: 'abc', att1:'val1'},
 {myKey: 'abc', att2:'val2'},
...
 {myKey: 'abc', attN:'valN'}
]
```

In other words, I need to form a pair of the attribute "myKey" with all other attributes of the object and present the result as an array.

The names of the other attributes are not fixed and can be any string other than "myKey".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert the key-values of an object to an array using the pluck() function. Removing the key `myKey` gives you a list of the `att*` key-values. Mapping this list you can get the expected result.

Example:

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var in={
    myKey: 'abc',
    att1:'val1',
    att2:'val2',
    att3:'val3'
    }

---
(in - "myKey") pluck {myKey: in.myKey,($$):$}
```

Output

```json
[
  {
    "myKey": "abc",
    "att1": "val1"
  },
  {
    "myKey": "abc",
    "att2": "val2"
  },
  {
    "myKey": "abc",
    "att3": "val3"
  }
]
```

Comment: Yes, thanks. My issue with the approach that is uses variable. While in I'm dealing with a long expression to get the array. So, is it possible to achieve this using pure functional expression without storing intermediate results in a variable?

Comment: Of course. DataWeave is a functional language. You can replace the expression to get a long one though may not be as readable. Or you could encapsulate the behavior into functions. The variable is basically a function with no arguments. The intention was to explain the method, no to provide the most modular implementation.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I've slightly simplified your version in the response.

Comment: It still demonstrates your idea - first removing the "myKey" property from the source object and then applying pluck on it.  The value of the "myKey" is preserved and then accessed from the input stored.